# How to access code in Project B without Adding Web Reference

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services

IDE: VS 2010, C# .net WInfomrs

I have two proejcts A and B
A: In A project I am doing UI Work
B: B project is responsible for Database functions, logics etc

I have a web service W and to use that service I have added that web reference in project A, so App.config is in project A.

Now I want to access and use WebService in Project B, Can you suggest is there any way to access it in project B without adding web service reference..

Basically I want to pass strXMLString, strFileName parameters to that web service

COde which I want to write in Project B:

```
 MyServiceSoapClient sc = new _MyServiceSoapClient ();
 sc.ReceiveXMLByContent("<tag1>text</tag1>", "myTest.xml");
```

I am able to write this code in project A, but can u suggest how to achieve same goal in project B.

I tried to overcome this issue by sending HttpPost, but getting error 500

```
/*
 //stack trace:  
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at UseWebServiceWithoutReference.Form1.button11_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in  

    C:\Users    \Yogesh\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\UseWebServiceWithoutReference\UseWebServiceWithoutReference\Form1.cs:line 369
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at UseWebServiceWithoutReference.Program.Main() in c:\users\Yogesh\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\UseWebServiceWithoutReference\UseWebServiceWithoutReference\Program.cs:line 18
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

webMathod:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string ReceiveXMLByContent(string strXMLData, string strXMLFileName)
    {
        XMLReceiver.Receive(strXMLData, strXMLFileName);
        return "Worked";
    }
```

client code

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string data = string.Format("strXMLData={0}&strXMLFileName={1}", "<tag1>text</tag1>", "myTest.xml");
        byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:50221/MyWebService.asmx/ReceiveXMLByContent");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;
        Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
        newStream.Close();
        var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string dataReturn = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(dataReturn);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

can you tell me what is the problem, behind error 500, when I am passing simple text instead of

```
 string data = string.Format("strXMLData={0}&strXMLFileName={1}", "<tag1>text</tag1>", "myTest.xml");  //Not working error 500  

string data = string.Format("strXMLData={0}&strXMLFileName={1}", "myTestString", "myTest.xml");//Working ..
```

Comment: calling project A's method from project B and do all operation in Project A only!!

Comment: why u don't want add web service reference in project B?

Comment: @Neel: I thing this idea is not good as it will causes a recursive reference error. Just a thought.

Comment: oh yes project A must having B's reference right @Avijit

Comment: Updated question, can you resolve HttpPost issue

Answer (score 0):

If i assume that your web service method look like this .

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string TestMethod(string data ,string fileName)
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
```

then you can use HttpWebRequest to call Web service without any web reference.

```
 string data = string.Format("data={0}&fileName={1}", "<tag1>text</tag1>", "myTest.xml");
            byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:63169/Service1.asmx/TestMethod");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;
            Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
            newStream.Close();
            var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            string dataReturn = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(dataReturn);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This is what I am trying but, In this way I am getting error 500, The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error; Added stack trace in question

Comment: did you try to put my method ? I also see that your method is return void so try something else as my example is working in one of my project.

Comment: yea, I tried using that way, getting same error, updated method in question

Comment: It seems some issue with encoding so I suggest you should send html encoded as content.

Comment: can you pls expain, I already tried using HTML encoding, but that also not working, that time I didn't got error, but I received empty string on server in first parameter,  I am new in this area can you explain a working code @dotnetstep

Answer (score 0):

Whoa - stop right there...

One of the commenters, @Avijit, has asked you a very good question - why do you want to avoid the web reference? You've not justified that requirement, and are now swimming very much against the tide looking for ingenious solutions to enable you to invoke a method without using a WebReference.

I think, before going any further down this line, you need to ask yourself what it is about the Web Reference that you are desperate to avoid. Your real problem, at least from where I am sitting, is not "How do I call a web service without a Web Reference?", but rather "How can I get around annoying property x of Web References..."

Comment: It would be better if you can tell me HTTP post approach, I don't want my clients to add web reference all the time, As HttpApproach is not working so I am trying using secondary approach -Using web reference, and yes project A is already having B's reference., I am able to access project B classes in Project A but not vice versa

Comment: Create a "WebProxies" project, stick your WebReference in there, and create references to that project from Projects A and B. Because B is a library, everything should still be driven from A's config. Web Service now callable from A and B...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have created my own Encoder and decoder:
I encoded xml before passing on server and decoded back on server

```
 private string MyHttpDecoder(string encodedXML)
    {
        //  string decoded = encodeXML.Replace("\\u003c", "<").Replace("\\u003e", ">").Replace("\"","");
        string decoded = encodedXML.Replace("66", "<").Replace("67", ">").Replace("68", "\"");
        return decoded;
    }  

private string MyHttpEncoder(string XML)
    {   
        string enc = XML.Replace("<", "66").Replace(">", "67").Replace("\"", "68");
        return enc;

    }
```

This worked charm.